# Self-defined function in PHP not working

Tags: php, jquery, function

Self-defined function in PHP not working for some cases.

Code:

```
<?php
function short_format_indian_c($n) {
    $precision = 3;
    $n_format = number_format($n / 1000, $precision);
    $n_format = number_format($n_format, 2);
    $n_format = $n_format + 0;
    $n_format = $n_format . ' K';
    return $n_format;
}
?>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var checkState = function(){  
        var tq = jQuery('#tq');
        tq.html(18000);
    }
    checkState();
    setInterval(checkState, 1000);
</script>
<?php $tq = '<span id="tq"></span>';?><?php echo short_format_indian_c($tq); ?>
```

If I use **echo short_format_indian_c(1800)** it is giving me the result as **18 K**.

But when I use **echo short_format_indian_c($tq)** it is giving me the result as **0 K**, where **$tq** is also **18000**

Comment: When you are passing `$tq` it goese like this:- `'<span id="tq">1800</span>';` and that's why you  are getting incorrect result.

Comment: @AlivetoDie--Anantsingh Ohh so is there any way where `tq=1800;` can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
echo short_format_indian_c($tq); // There $tq not have any number only value thats why this not give a proper output.

?>


    <?php
    //This code run only server side.

    function short_format_indian_c($n) {
        $precision = 3;
        $n_format = number_format($n / 1000, $precision);
        $n_format = number_format($n_format, 2);
        $n_format = $n_format + 0;
        $n_format = $n_format . ' K';
        return $n_format;
    }
   // As per User need.

   function kFormatter($num) {
      // return ($num > 999) ?(round(($num/1000),2).'K':$num; //Not return K for less than 1000 ;
      return round(($num/1000),2).'K'; // work for all numbers

    } 
    ?>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        //This part only run at client side.
        function kFormatter(num) {
          // return num > 999 ? (num/1000).toFixed(1) + 'K' : num; //Not return K for less than 1000 ;
          return (num/1000).toFixed(1) + 'K'; // work for all numbers

        } 
        // Function for all format indian Currency.

       function short_format_indian_c(num) {


if(num < 1000)
      {
        return num; // For Less then 1000
      }
      else if(num >= 1000 && num < 99999)
      {
        return (num/1000).toFixed(1) + 'K'; // for 1000 multiplier till 99999
      }
      else if(num >= 100000 && num < 9999999)
      {
        return (num/100000).toFixed(1) + 'L'; // for 100000 multiplier till 9999999
      }
      else if(num >= 10000000 && num < 999999999)
      {
        return (num/10000000).toFixed(1) + 'C'; // for 10000000 multiplier till 999999999
      }
      else
      {
        return num; // For all other num instead
      }

    } 
        var checkState = function(){  
            var tq = jQuery('#tq');

            tq.html(short_format_indian_c(18000));
            // This will provide an output as 18K in element have id is tq;

        }
    checkState();
    setInterval(checkState, 1000);
    </script>
    <?php 
    $tq = '<span id="tq"></span>'; // Wrong way to assign html value in a php variable.
    $tq  = '18000'; // this will work instead.

    ?>
    <?php 
    echo short_format_indian_c($tq); // There $tq not have any number only value thats why this not give a proper output.

    ?>
```

**Note!** if there you required a result at client side then you need to write this function for javascript also; [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e63jz6gu/2/)

Comment: So, I have to write `function short_format_indian_c()` in javascript? How to do so? I will be helpful if you add that code to the answer too.

Comment: There is no output after trying your updated answer. See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e63jz6gu/)

Comment: Looks something is wrong with `$n_format = $n_format . ' K';`

Comment: yes because `.` not a string concatenate operator it must be replaced by `+` and also there no `number_format` function in JavaScript so you need some changes.  try the updated answer may this work for you.

Comment: Yes, it helped me, ready to accept the answer. but the function I provided was a part. And you changed `PHP` function to `Javascript` function. I will be more helpful if you change my full `PHP` [function](https://jsfiddle.net/e63jz6gu/3/) to the `javascript` function.

Comment: But my friend your PHP Function works well.So why you want to change this.Let's check the updated answer for the same.

Comment: But the function in the answer will only do for thousands. I need for Lacs and Crore too. My `PHP` function do that too. And now I want that Full function with javascript function. [Here is my full PHP function](https://jsfiddle.net/e63jz6gu/3/)

Comment: Check the updated answer there a function added in script part named `short_format_indian_c` check this may this work for you.

Comment: You can also upvote this to help other users for a better solution for future.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your function expects one parameter. When you call it in your code

```
<?php echo short_format_indian_c($tq); ?>
```

You pass $tq as an argument. $tq at the moment is equal to ""

```
<?php $tq = '<span id="tq"></span>';?>
```

Inside of your function you perform a division on argument which in this case is a string. As a result of that process string will be casted to int and will be equal to 0. So you will get 0 K.

On the other hand, when you pass 18000 as an argument everything will work as you expect.

Comment: But I need it for the client-side